# Write binary/hexadecimal value into .bin file from list of string/int

Tags: c#, hex, binarywriter

I want to write a long list of binary number into a binary file from a list. The list are now all Hexadecimal number. My code below is not giving what i want like case 1, instead it output case 2. Please help.

Case 1: What i need is a binary file - 1A0F83.....

Case 2: but not - 314130463833.....

```
List<string> list = new List<string>(new string[]{"1A", "0F", "83" }); 

using (var s = File.Open("test.bin", FileMode.Create))
{
    var tw = new BinaryWriter(s);                

    foreach (string i in list) // Loop through all strings
    {               
        tw.Write(i);    
    }                             
}
```

Comment: Can you describe in what way you think your code is wrong? Is it not writing, or writing the incorrect output? Some other error?

Comment: Your code won't compile. You have to use the hexadecimal value prefix.

Comment: Where does `listC` come from? It mysteriously appears in the `foreach` loop... Also, isn't your list of `int` really a list of `byte`?

Comment: `string i in listC` - don't you mean `int i in list` ?

Comment: dymanoid, Matthew Watson and Cubrr, yes i cut part of my code out into this question, and something is missing/wrongly declared. i edited the questions and now it is compile-able. the solution that match my need is listed by haindl below. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to write a sequence of single bytes to a binary file then just write a single `byte` at a time (not an `int` which is 4 bytes in size) and change the following line

```
tw.Write(i);
```

to this:

```
tw.Write((byte)i);
```

Or if you want to clean up your code a little bit, increase the performance for longer sequences and make it compilable too, you can just use this:

```
var list = new List<byte> { 0x1A, 0x0F, 0x83 }.ToArray();

using (var s = File.Open("test.bin", FileMode.Create))
using (var tw = new BinaryWriter(s))
    tw.Write(list);
```

Comment: Your solution helped in my case. But i have million of data which converted from int to hex. Now i need to figure out how to convert my list to this byte with prefix. Thanks!

Comment: @LipFong You're welcome! If you have another problem for which you can't find a solution here (or in your favorite search engine) then you can just ask another question.

Comment: @LipFong I've now seen your last edit. Just as an additional hint - if you have a list of strings and want to convert them into bytes, you can just do the following: `var list = new List<string> { "1A" }.Select(s => byte.Parse(s, NumberStyles.HexNumber)).ToArray();`